# Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) registration token server-side validation

Tags: android, ios, http, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm updating a backend service that sends push notifications to iOS and Android devices through *Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)* HTTP APIs.

I noticed that we were using the [legacy "HTTP Server Protocol"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) and now i'm trying to port our service to ["FCM HTTP v1 API"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages).

Sending a notification, in the previous protocol version responses, there were [some error messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) (see "Unregistered Device") to identify expired registration tokens. Now I receive a response with a "name" field containing a mysterious "message_id":

```
{ "name" : "projects/{project_id}/messages/{message_id}" }
```

I've even tried to send some notifications to very old tokens/devices without receiving any error.

- How can I detect the registration tokens that are not working
  anymore using the current version of the APIs?
- Is there any documentation about the possible "send" API error responses?
- Bonus: when were released the current "FCM HTTP v1 API"?

I'm also considering to expire tokens on a time or app usage base.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The doc says when the request was successful, the response contains an instance of the message.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send

When the token is not available anymore we get a FileNotFoundException (in java) when we want to read the response. You can simple test this by deleting the app.

The "FCM HTTP v1 API" was announced at the last Firebase Dev Summit: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/whats-new-at-firebase-dev-summit-2017.html

Comment: Oh.. I had some feelings that these APIs were new, but not SO new!  Making a request with another old token I managed to get a 404 error, but keeping in mind the "empirical" discover method we used and the lack of precise documentation it feels a little "temporary"... Thanks!

Comment: Yes I also managed to have a 404 error with an revoked token. But what's happened with all the other possibilities like internal error or token updated ?

Comment: @brozot, THAT is the question... I've keep this question open exactly because I hope there will be some updates.

Comment: Were you able to find a proper way to validate tokens as of 2019?